# Mapping duration with NHibernate

Tags: .net, sql-server, view, nhibernate-mapping, timespan

I have a database view (Sql Server 2005) that has a column Duration (EndDate - StartDate) and I want that to be mapped to a TimeSpan property in .NET.

So far my best guess is to convert it in the view to an int, like this:

```
DATEDIFF(ms, StartDate, EndDate) * 10000 AS Duration
```

... but that seems an ugly solution to me.

What is the best way to do that?

**EDIT:**
I also tried using a formula:

```
<property name="Duration" formula="EndDate - StartDate" type="timespan" />
```

... but that also generates an error (Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int64') so there's not added value there.

Comment: does `formula="DATEIFF('ms', EndDate, BeginDate) * 1000"` work?

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact answer to your question, but... I would perform the difference in my nhibernate class.

myclass.cs

```
public virtual DateTime dstart {get;set;}
public virtual DateTime dend {get;set;}

// This property not being part oh nhibernate mapping
public TimeSpan MyDifference
{
  get {return dend.Subtract(dstart);
}
```

This way, you do not overload the RDBMS performing innecesary substracts when performing selects, and you make the calculation only when needed. It it not a mapped property nor does need to be (read only anyway).
MyDifference can be used and nowone can tell or cares how or who makes the calculation

Hope this helps

Comment: I need them for display in an overview grid. This way I cannot apply sorting on the duration column in a generic way, so no option for me...

Comment: Are you sure?? I cant see why not

Comment: Because sorting should be handled by Sql Server and not in loaded objects in memory (pure efficiency). We also do paging, so we first need to sort the data and then grab the appropriate page. If we would have sorting on the duration column in memory then we'd have to load the whole resultset in memory, then sort it and then grab the page from memory. That's not efficient...